# Uncaught Error: Accounts.ui.config: `extraSignupFields` must be an array

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor Release 0.8.1.3 with accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, I have installed accounts-google, accounts-facebook accounts-password

When the application starts, I see the following error in the JavaScript console:

> Uncaught Error: Accounts.ui.config: `extraSignupFields` must be an array.

I have the following code in one of the client .js files:

```
  Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        facebook: ['user_likes'],
        google: [
            'email',
            'profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
        ]
    },
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});
```

If I remove the code the error message goes away.

BTW, when I run this on localhost:3000 I can still login with Google, Facebook etc. When i run it on AWS or Heroku I get and additional error and the app won't start, I am including it incase it helps work out what the problem is:

> Exception in defer callback: Error: No uiManager configured on Router

I am not sure if this is a result of the first error.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` is known to cause such problems. The first one you can easily solve by adding `extraSignupFields` to the `config` call:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    ...
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL',
  extraSignupFields: [],
});
```